# Many to Many inside Many to Many Table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have a Table **Orders** which contains a List of **Products**. For each of the **Products** corresponding to the specific Order I need to store a List of **Addresses** where individual product(per Order per Product basis) should be delivered to

```
+----------------+------------+
|    Order_ID    | Product_ID |
+----------------+------------+
| 1              |       1000 |
| 2              |       1000 |
| 2              |       1001 |
+----------------+------------+
```

So I have this table which is a many to many on **Orders** and **Products** what I need is to map each of the entries in the above table to a List of **Addresses**. So I need something like

```
|PK|Order_ID |Product_ID |    
| 1|    1    |  1000     |
| 2|    2    |  1000     |
| 3|    2    |  1001     |
```

and to map an entry in the above table to a list of Addresses I need another many to many table on the above PK and Address ID(primary key of my address table)

```
|PK_Order_Product |Address_ID|
|    1            |  1       |
|    2            |  1       |
|    2            |  3       |
```

Here PK_Order_Product is the foreign key on the previous table's primary key(PK)
I am using JPA for persisting into my MYSQL DB Please help me with a code snippet if my design is correct.How to do this in Java using JPA annotations

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is this design correct? Can I have a better design. If yes how do I do this using JPA

Comment: JPA is designed around classes. Post your classes

Comment: class Order{   
 long orderId;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a good question that is worth some research and experimenting. There are many ways to do the mapping. Coming up with a better design would actually depend on your application needs. But here is how I think would be an effective way to implement the mapping:

I'll have 3 separate entities for `Order`, `Product` and `Address`.

We will not implement the usual many-to-many relationship between the 2 entities, `Order` and `Product`, where each side has a collection of the other. Instead, I'll create another entity to represent the relationship between `Order` and `Product`, and let's name it `ProductOrder`. Here's how their relationships are mapped:

- `Order` has one-to-many relationship with `ProductOrder`.
- `ProductOrder` has many-to-one relationship with `Order`.
- `Product` has one-to-many relationship with `ProductOrder`.
- `ProductOrder` has many-to-one relationship with `Product`.

`ProductOrder`'s primary key will be composed of the primary key of `Order` and primary key of `Product` - so this will be a composite key. Therefore we will need to use `@IdClass` to map composite keys.

Now, here's the trick to achieving the many-to-many within a many-to-many relationship:

`ProductOrder` has many-to-many relationship with `Address`.

See sample codes for each entity mentioned above:

**ORDER ENTITY**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ORDERS")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ORDER_ID")
    private Long id;

    private int quantity;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order")
    private List<ProductOrder> productOrderList = new ArrayList<ProductOrder>();
...
}
```

---

**PRODUCT ENTITY**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCT")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    private List<ProductOrder> productOrderList = new ArrayList<ProductOrder>();
...
}
```

---

**ADDRESS ENTITY**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ADDRESS")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
    private Long id;

    private String state;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "addressList")
    private List<ProductOrder> productOrderList = new ArrayList<ProductOrder>();
...
}
```

---

**PRODUCTORDER ENTITY**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCT_ORDER")
@IdClass(ProductOrderId.class)
public class ProductOrder {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ORDER_ID")
    private Order order;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PRODUCT_ID")
    private Product product;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="PRODUCT_ORDER_ADDRESS",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ORDER_ID", referencedColumnName="ORDER_ID"),
                    @JoinColumn(name="PRODUCT_ID", referencedColumnName="PRODUCT_ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ADDRESS_ID", referencedColumnName="ADDRESS_ID"))
    private List<Address> addressList = new ArrayList<Address>();
...
}
```

---

**@IdClass for ProductOrder entity**

```
public class ProductOrderId {

    private Long order;
    private Long product;
...
}
```

---

Here's a sample code for creating the entities and persisting them:

```
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    Order order = new Order();
    order.setQuantity(10);
    em.persist(order);

    Product product = new Product();
    product.setName("Coffee");
    em.persist(product);

    Address address = new Address();
    address.setState("CA");
    em.persist(address);

    ProductOrder productOrder = new ProductOrder();
    productOrder.setOrder(order);
    productOrder.setProduct(product);

    productOrder.getAddressList().add(address);
    address.getProductOrderList().add(productOrder);

    em.persist(productOrder);

    em.getTransaction().commit();
```

---

Here's how the schema was generated in MySQL database:

```
Hibernate: 
    create table ADDRESS (
        ADDRESS_ID bigint not null auto_increment,
        state varchar(255),
        primary key (ADDRESS_ID)
    )
Hibernate: 
    create table ORDERS (
        ORDER_ID bigint not null auto_increment,
        quantity integer not null,
        primary key (ORDER_ID)
    )
Hibernate: 
    create table PRODUCT (
        PRODUCT_ID bigint not null auto_increment,
        name varchar(255),
        primary key (PRODUCT_ID)
    )
Hibernate: 
    create table PRODUCT_ORDER (
        ORDER_ID bigint,
        PRODUCT_ID bigint,
        primary key (ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_ID)
    )
Hibernate: 
    create table PRODUCT_ORDER_ADDRESS (
        ORDER_ID bigint not null,
        PRODUCT_ID bigint not null,
        ADDRESS_ID bigint not null
    )
Hibernate: 
    alter table PRODUCT_ORDER 
        add constraint FK_sl39bwx60xjbvoiujpaes74ty 
        foreign key (ORDER_ID) 
        references ORDERS (ORDER_ID)
Hibernate: 
    alter table PRODUCT_ORDER 
        add constraint FK_n0i7uxq6rxsc0mcred1cds4m9 
        foreign key (PRODUCT_ID) 
        references PRODUCT (PRODUCT_ID)
Hibernate: 
    alter table PRODUCT_ORDER_ADDRESS 
        add constraint FK_kad6crei9lgrv1nuuuff42vs8 
        foreign key (ADDRESS_ID) 
        references ADDRESS (ADDRESS_ID)
Hibernate: 
    alter table PRODUCT_ORDER_ADDRESS 
        add constraint FK_hpx0e467dvpqi5i6kxmujns2b 
        foreign key (ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_ID) 
        references PRODUCT_ORDER (ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_ID)
```

Comment: I am getting the below errors

**Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: ADDRESS_ID in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(ADDRESS) and its related supertables and secondary tables** 

Can you help me with the solution

Comment: `@Entity
@Table(name="ADDRESS")
 public class Address implements Serializable , IEntity{
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name="ADDRESS_ID")
 private Long pk;

 @Column(name="address_name", nullable=false, length=255)
 private String addressName;
}`

Comment: do you use hbm2ddl auto? is it set to CREATE or UPDATE?

Comment: Ok, kindly update the question and post the code of all your entities, so we can see all the mappings if they are correctly declared. Posting code here in the comments section is not readable. Or any method you think that is faster to share that information...

Comment: its the copy paste of your solution provided above Is the solution you provided a **working** solution?

Comment: I find it really weird. I suggest you remove the `referencedColumnName` attributes.

Comment: It is a working solution, in fact I had it running and even gave you the hibernate logs showing the generated schema/tables. I can share you the code in some repository i.e. GitHub if you want.

Comment: That will be really great if you share the **GitHub** link.

Comment: Sorry, it took a while uploading it. It's a Maven project. Here's the link: https://github.com/balagueri21/sample-codes/tree/master/ManyToManySpecial