# Better way for Entity Relations in Many-to-Many Mapping between 3 Tables

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have a many-to-many relation between 3 tables X , Y , Z

So I created  a table X_Y_Mapping and used the primary key of that table for another mapping table X_Y_KEY_Z_MAPPING which has FK to X_Y_MAPPING and Z.

Another way is have a X_Y_Z table , But I will come to it later...

Now, since I am using JPA, I find no other way than creating an separate entity for X_Y_KEY_Z_MAPPING table.

But, won't this add an extra overhead if I am trying to save mapping between Z and other entities since I need to check whether Mapping exists  between x and y for the same.

Is there another way to create many-to-many mapping between these tables without using X_Y_KEY_Z_MAPPING table as an entity but with NO Change in DB structure, as in I keep the table X_Y_KEY_Z_MAPPING ?

Is creating a direct mapping table X_Y_Z the only other way?

Comment: Maybe my answer in this post can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181733/many-to-many-inside-many-to-many-table

Comment: The Answer says to use composite keys ... That makes it complicated , Can't I work with auto generated simple Ids ?

Comment: Also in your answer .. What is the use of PRODUCT_ORDER , When you are creating PRODUCT_ORDER_ADDRESS ?  Seems Redundant.